# Como añadir un Select dentro de una grafica HIGHCHARTS

Tags: php, html, highcharts

estaba tratando de añadir un select a mi grafica, para que interactue dentro de la grafica... este es el codigo:

```
       <?php
        include("conexion.php");
               $result4 =$con->query("SELECT grupo_asignado,semana 
 ,COUNT(incidencia) AS ver FROM `registro_inci` where 
      YEAR(fecha_sin_horas)=YEAR(NOW()) group by semana,grupo_asignado");
                  $d=0;
                  while($row_INCIDE= mysqli_fetch_array($result4, 
      MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                  {
                      $cat[$d] = $row_INCIDE["grupo_asignado"];
                      $cat2[$d] = $row_INCIDE["ver"];
                      $d++;
                  }
                  /*$unir="";
                  for ($i=0; $i <$d ; $i++) { 
                    $unir=$unir.$cat2[$i].",";
                  }*/
                  $a_u="";
                  $b_u="";
                  $c_u="";
                  for ($i=0; $i <$d ; $i++) { 
                    if ($cat[$i]=="Emergencia Lima Este") {
                        $a_u=$a_u.$cat2[$i].",";
                    }
                    if ($cat[$i]=="Emergencia Lima Norte") {
                        $b_u=$b_u.$cat2[$i].",";
                    }
                    if ($cat[$i]=="Emergencia Lima Norte Chico") {
                        $c_u=$c_u.$cat2[$i].",";
                    }

                  }
                  $alm[0]=$a_u;
                  $alm[1]=$b_u;
                  $alm[2]=$c_u;
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

de aca saco la informacion(lo cual extraigo de una base de datos) para presentar en la grafica,lo cual lo cargo de esta manera:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('#grafica_INCIDE').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'INCIDENCIAS POR SEMANA Y POR ZONA'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'des Enero-2018 hasta la fecha'
        },
        xAxis: {
              categories: [<?php for($y=1;$y<=$d-1;$y++){ echo "'sem 
        ".$y."',";}?>]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'numero de incidencias'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'k'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 4,
                    lineColor: '#666666',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
        <?php for($y=0;$y<=2;$y++){ ?>
                    {
                        name: <?php  echo "'".$cat[$y]."',";  ?>
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'diamond'
                        },
                        data: [
                        <?php 
                        echo $alm[$y];                                                                          
                        ?>]
                    },
                    <?php } ?>]
    });
});


    </script>
```

entonces la grafica se me de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero mi pregunta seria si es que se puede añadir un select(como el de html) dentro de esta grafica

Comment: @JackNavaRow lo que tu dices es duplicado es muy distinto a mi solicotud, ya que en el wordpress de tu enlace lo hace por fechas, pero mi consulta es que, por ejemplo, tenga un numero de personales, cada uno realiza una cantidad x mes, y en mi grafica sale el total, pero ¿como haria si es que solo quiero ver como le va a un personal en especifico?

Comment: solo te digo por el manejo de fechas y un ajax que invoca carga nuevamente los datos que es lo que tu quieres mira http://jsfiddle.net/5dszcfq7/1/